# Golang 'hashicorp/serf' library in docker-compose connection problem

Tags: go, serf

I have a set of Golang services that utilize Serf nodes, and when I run them locally, everything works as expected. The services are able to discover and join each other successfully.

However, when I run the service within a Docker Compose environment, I encounter an issue. Other services running outside the container fail to join the service running inside the container. The discovery process seems to be failing.

Starting serf process

```
func startSD() {
    addr := "127.0.0.1:50055"
    h := &SDHandler{}
    var err error
    mems, err = discovery.New(h, discovery.Config{
        NodeName:       fmt.Sprintf("sd-%s", addr),
        BindAddr:       addr,
        StartJoinAddrs: []string{},
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}
```

Configuring serf node

```
func (m *Membership) setupSerf() (err error) {
    addr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", m.BindAddr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    config := serf.DefaultConfig()
    config.Init()
    config.MemberlistConfig.BindAddr = addr.IP.String()
    config.MemberlistConfig.BindPort = addr.Port

    m.events = make(chan serf.Event)

    config.EventCh = m.events
    config.Tags = m.Tags
    config.NodeName = m.Config.NodeName

    m.serf, err = serf.Create(config)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go m.eventHandler()

    if m.StartJoinAddrs != nil {
        _, err = m.serf.Join(m.StartJoinAddrs, true)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  media-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "50050:50050"
      - "50055:50055"
      - "50055:50055/udp"
```

Error I get trying to connect to the service inside container

```
 [DEBUG] memberlist: Failed to join 127.0.0.1:50055: EOF
```

**UPD**

I've changed address of BindAddr to this:

```
addr := ":50055"
```

However, I am encountering some issues where the nodes join the cluster but then leave after a few seconds and errors:

```
2023/05/31 14:54:47 [ERR] memberlist: Failed to send gossip to [::]:50055: write udp 127.0.0.1:50051->[::]:50055: address ::: non-IPv4 address
2023/05/31 14:54:48 [ERR] memberlist: Failed to send UDP ping: write udp 127.0.0.1:50051->[::]:50055: address ::: non-IPv4 address
2023/05/31 14:54:49 [WARN] memberlist: Was able to connect to f34f34g34g34gerg over TCP but UDP probes failed, network may be misconfigured
2023/05/31 14:54:50 [ERR] memberlist: Failed to send UDP ping: write udp 127.0.0.1:50051->[::]:50055: address ::: non-IPv4 address
```

Comment: Try change the BindAddr from localhost (127.0.0.1) to an empty addr - ":50055". You probably also have to change NodeName to something unique.

Comment: @nevilad I've added UPD. Seems like it started to works but has problems anyway

Comment: Passing "0.0.0.0:50055" should force it to use IPv4 only.

Comment: Do you mean to pass it here? addr := "0.0.0.0:50055"

Comment: I got errors after changing BindAddr to 0.0.0.0:50055:  [ERR] memberlist: Failed to send gossip to 172.20.0.2:50055: write udp 127.0.0.1:50051->172.20.0.2:50055: sendto: can't assign requested address

Comment: Don't know exactly what this error means, but would dig in the direction why 127.0.0.1 appears in the addresses. This address means localhost, when you ran all your services on same machine they were able to discover because had the same host. On different machines they have different "localhosts".